# Exception:Reverted when swap by smart contrat with uniswap

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, kovan

Here is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;
import "https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v2-periphery/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol"; 

contract Test_Swap{

  address owner = msg.sender;     
  
  IUniswapV2Router02 uniswap = IUniswapV2Router02(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);
  
  address private token_address = 0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA; //chainlink
  address private usdc = 0x0D9C8723B343A8368BebE0B5E89273fF8D712e3C;
  
  function getPathForETHtoToken() private view returns (address[] memory) {
     address[] memory path = new address[](2);
     path[0] = uniswap.WETH();
     path[1] = usdc;
   return path;
   }
   
  function swapContractEthToLink() external payable {  
  uniswap.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(0,getPathForETHtoToken(), owner, block.timestamp + 15);  
  }
}
```

I'm trying to trade for my ethers for usdc, but I'm getting an [error](https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x68e0bab7017f498bba18bc32ab84a364a9e37b98b37421ff7ff5579bb4bfcd4a)

I'm using a remix, deploying my contract on kovan

I apologize for my english (google translator) and maybe a stupid question, I'm a beginner, I will be grateful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work on **Kovan** because your USDC Token address is invalid on **Kovan**, you can see that the address `0x0D9C8723B343A8368BebE0B5E89273fF8D712e3C` is an empty address on **Kovan**

https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x0D9C8723B343A8368BebE0B5E89273fF8D712e3C

while on **Ropsten** it is the valid USDC Token

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0D9C8723B343A8368BebE0B5E89273fF8D712e3C

I guess the USDC team just didn't deploy their token on **Kovan**, so of course when you try to swap WETH to USDC on **Kovan** it is reverted.

Comment: I tried other tokens, apparently for the same reason it didn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was necessary to change the test network to **ropsten**, it is strange because the same contracts are displayed and work in the test network **kovan**